# How to enable tab key navigation on a datagrid where the cells are custom item renderers?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, datagrid, itemrenderer

This is a snippet of code in our custom item renderer which is in actionscript:

```
textCustomItemRendererTempForTab.tabEnabled=true;
textCustomItemRendererTempForTab.focusEnabled=true;
textCustomItemRendererTempForTab.setFocus();
Alert.show( "Without this alert focus goes to next grid   " );
keyboardEvent.preventDefault();
keyboardEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
keyboardEvent.stopPropagation();
```

Right now tab navigation works (on tab, focus goes to next editable cell) with the alert inserted in the code but I'm not sure why because I believe the alert in the code breaks the flow of event bubbling. However without the alert (which is what we are going for) the focus goes to the next grid in our UI.

You can see the attempts of trying to stop the event from going to other components. I have also tried to call preventDefault() and stopPropagation() on the datagrid when it receives a tab key event.

Any ideas on how to allow proper tab key navigation without an alert?

Comment: I used the example here: http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/04/08/creating-a-self-closing-alert-control-in-flex/ to quickly close the alert and that works however the screen blinks and it's a hack at best.

Comment: Provide more code and we may be able to provide more assistance.  From the snippet you provided; it is hard to tell what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
keyboardEvent.preventDefault();
keyboardEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
keyboardEvent.stopPropagation();
textCustomItemRendererTempForTab.tabEnabled=true;
textCustomItemRendererTempForTab.focusEnabled=true;
callLater(function():void {
    textCustomItemRendererTempForTab.setFocus();
});
```